# Excel VBA - Convert existing image in cell to comment picture

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use VBA in Excel to convert a bunch of pictures in a column (one per cell) to a pop up comment image instead so that the sheet is more easily readable. 
I can find the image I need by iterating through the shapes, and I can set this as an object; but I can't seem to use that onject to populate the comment field. It seems to be looking for a true file path instead.
I don't particularly want to have to save each image and then reload it, seems kind of pointless.

```
 For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Pic.TopLeftCell.Address = ActiveCell.Address Then
      If Pic.Type = msoPicture Then
        Pic.Select
        Application.ActiveCell.AddComment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture **(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Pic.name))** 'if I use a path here its okay
        'SelectPictureAtActiveCell = name
        Exit For
      End If
    End If
   Next
```

any thoughts?

CJ

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to show one image if you select a specific cell then

See

[Making shapes invisible/visible in excel through VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573566/making-shapes-invisible-visible-in-excel-through-vba)

with

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Macro1
End Sub
```

You can make images hide and show  using
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ImageName").Visible = False or True

for example when you click on cell A1 first image is hidden else all images are visible

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim shp As Shape

If ActiveCell.Address = "$A$1" Then
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Visible = False
' or you can use image name as
'ActiveSheet.Shapes("ImageName").Visible = False
'shp.Visible = False
Next
Else
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
shp.Visible = True
Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: and then using cell and image combination you can hide and show multiple images

Comment: thanks for the reply. No, i'm not trying to hide the images, i want to convert them to a comment. similar to here: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/vba-insert-image-into-cell-comment  however, I have the images already in a cell, i just want to convert them to a comment. I have it wokring by saving the image then adding it as above, but seems unncessary to save first

Comment: I thought making images popup would be really irritating if you move mouse and it will not be easily readable. Selecting a cell to show the corresponding image seems to be good. But if you want images to popup, you can check mousemove event in VBA.  I am not sure about that. But thanks I learnt to hide and show images on cell select.