# Excel show image from http response

Tags: excel, vba, image, http

The goal is to have a sheet in excel that contains fields and a button. The click on button will create url from the fields and create a HTTP GET request that returns an image in raw data. This image then should be shown in the current sheet.

This is what i have already done:

```
Sub GetQrCode()
Dim hReq As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1

Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "https://www.profit365.eu/services/API/QR/PayBySquare.png?IBAN=SK2311000000001234567890&BIC=TATRSKBX&Currency=EUR&Amount=123.40&DueDate=41763&VS=1234568&SS=&CS=&size=256"

Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .Send
    End With

Dim resp As String
resp = hReq.responseBody

End Sub
```

Now should come the code that shows the resp (raw image).

Is this possible? Has anyone done something similar?

Thank you for the responses

Comment: Hint: -- With `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL)` statement you can directly insert image from url in excel sheet. Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62264232/9808063) and the link in its comments

Comment: Does it work when the URL is not in format that ends ".png"?