# excel show/hide group based on combobox selection

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I need some help to figure out how to unhide/hide a group based on an activeX combo box selection.

I currently have two groups (group_1 and group_2) and a combobox (activeX) with two selections (2021-2022 and 2022-2023).

When 2021-2022 is selected from the drop down, I want group_1 to be unhidden (it is hidden by default).

When 2022-2023 is selected from the drop down, I want group_1 to be hidden and group_2 unhidden (it is hidden by default).

I am very new to VBA and have tried to put some code together for the first group and drop down selection option, but I have had no luck.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change_2()
    Select Case ComboBox1.Text
        Case "2021-2022"
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("group_1")
                If .Visible = False Then .Visible = True Else .Visible = False
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Is this something that can be done?

Comment: In a past scenario which was similar, I looped through all shapes to hide and used `select; case "my string"` to make visible.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573566/making-shapes-invisible-visible-in-excel-through-vba) has some related info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim txt
    txt = ComboBox1.Text
    With Me 'assuming this is in the worksheet code module
        .Shapes("group_1").Visible = txt = "2021-2022"
        .Shapes("group_2").Visible = txt = "2022-2023"
        .Shapes("group_3").Visible = Len(txt) > 0 'any option selected
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you but have come across an issue. It doesn't seem to 'self activate'. If I set the drop down on 2021-2022 and then run the code the relevant group appears, however if I just try to change the selection in the drop down nothing happens. Like the code isn't being automatically executed on selection?

Comment: `ComboBox1_Change_2` seems like the wrong name for the Sub? Should probably be  `ComboBox1_Change` assuming your combobox is called `ComboBox1`

Comment: Does that usually matter? reason is that I have a previous sub command to change the text colour of the ComboBox1, being ComboBox1_change, so the name isn't unique and needs to be something different, hence the _2 added on the end for the command. I did change this in the code you supplied.

Comment: Update: I merged the code for the colour properties and the one you supplied and it works!

Comment: One more extension to this, how can I make a new group (group_3) visible only if any option is selected in the ComboBox1?

Comment: See the edit above: you can just check that `ComboBox1.Text` is not empty.